# iexpress extract files then run vbs referencing files from within the exe

Tags: vbscript, hta, iexpress

I am having trouble getting vbs to work with iexpress.
I'm trying get the exe file to open a vbs that opens a hta held in the exe. but when i do, i get a blank hta located in %temp%.

My question is; how do i get vbs to correctly locate the unpack location of iexpress, so my script opens the hta extracted from the exe instead of a blank %temp% file?

I have tried doing it like this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe " & 
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory &"\page.hta"
```

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/a/29043160/603855 helps (diff between current and script's directory)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the files were simply removed before i could access them, as the exe file deletes itself before the vbs is able to fetch the other files. it was not that the directory was wrong.