# Move file to relative parent directory

Tags: vbscript, parent, relative-path

I know how to get the relative current directory using

```
.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

but how do I get the relative parent of the parent?  I'm trying to move a file up 1 directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply .GetParentFolderName() twice:

```
>> WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptFullName
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(goFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName))
>>
M:\bin\ivbs.wsf
M:\bin
M:\
```

P.S.: the current directory is not necessarily the script's directory (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29043160/603855)).

Comment: Says "file already exists", which makes me think it's trying to place it back in the same directory.  Trying to use like this: set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") csvfilename = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\AgentData.csv" fso.movefile csvfilename, fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)).  Running this script in the same directory as the "AgentData.csv" file.

Comment: Figured it out, had to add a backslash like this: fso.movefile csvfilename, fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)) & "\"